# Exercise 19 on p.39 in Exercises 2B in "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler. Is my solution ok? How to simplify these conditions?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

I am reading "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.
The following exercise is Exercise 19 on p.39 in Exercises 2B in this book.

> Exercise 19
> Suppose $X$ is a nonempty set and $\mathcal{S}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ consisting of all subsets of $X$ that are either countable or have a countable complement in $X$. Give a characterization of the $\mathcal{S}$-measurable real-valued functions on $X$.

My solution is here:

> Let $f$ be an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable real-valued function on $X.$
> Let $A:=\{a\in\mathbb{R}:f^{-1}((a,\infty))\text{ is countable}\}.$
> We prove that $A$ is not empty.
> Assume that $A=\emptyset.$
> Then, $f^{-1}((a,\infty))$ is uncountable for any $a\in\mathbb{R}.$
> Then, $X\setminus f^{-1}((a,\infty))=f^{-1}((-\infty,a])$ is countable for any $a\in\mathbb{R}.$
> Since $X=f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})=f^{-1}(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} (-\infty,n])=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}f^{-1}((-\infty,n])$, $X$ is countable.
> Let $a\in\mathbb{R}.$
> Since $f^{-1}((a,\infty))\subset X$, $f^{-1}((a,\infty))$ is countable.
> This is a contradiction.
> So, $A$ is not empty.
> Let $a_1\in A.$
> Let $a_2$ be any element of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $a_1<a_2.$
> Then, $f^{-1}((a_2,\infty))\subset f^{-1}((a_1,\infty)).$
> Since $f^{-1}((a_1,\infty))$ is countable, $f^{-1}((a_2,\infty))$ is countable.
> So, if $a_1\in A$, then $a_2\in A$ for any $a_2\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a_1<a_2.$
> So,
>
> - if $A$ is not bounded below, $A=\mathbb{R},$
> - if $A$ is bounded below, $A=(b,\infty)$ or $A=[b,\infty)$ for some $b\in\mathbb{R}.$
>
> First, we consider the case $A=(b,\infty)$ for some $b\in\mathbb{R}.$
> $f^{-1}((b,\infty))$ is uncountable since $b\notin A.$
> So, $f^{-1}((-\infty,b])=X\setminus f^{-1}((b,\infty))$ is countable.
> Let $\epsilon$ be any positive real number.
> Then, $f^{-1}((b+\epsilon,\infty))$ is countable since $b+\epsilon\in A.$
> Therefore, $f^{-1}((b,b+\epsilon])=f^{-1}((b,\infty))\setminus f^{-1}((b+\epsilon,\infty))$ is uncountable.
>
> Next, we consider the case $A=[b,\infty)$ for some $b\in\mathbb{R}.$
> $f^{-1}((b,\infty))$ is countable since $b\in A.$
> Let $\epsilon$ be any positive real number.
> $f^{-1}((b-\epsilon,\infty))$ is uncountable since $b-\epsilon\notin A.$
> $f^{-1}((-\infty,b-\epsilon])=X\setminus f^{-1}((b-\epsilon,\infty))$ is countable.
> $f^{-1}((b-\epsilon,b])=f^{-1}((b-\epsilon,\infty))\setminus f^{-1}((b,\infty))$ is uncountable.
>
> Conversely, let $f$ be a real-valued function on $X$ which satisfies one of the following conditions:
>
> 1. $f^{-1}((a,\infty))$ is countable for any $a\in\mathbb{R}.$
> 2. There exists $b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for any positive real number $\epsilon$, $f^{-1}((b+\epsilon,\infty))$ is countable  and $f^{-1}((b,b+\epsilon])$ is uncountable and $f^{-1}((-\infty,b])$ is countable.
> 3. There exists $b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for any positive real number $\epsilon$, $f^{-1}((b,\infty))$ is countable  and $f^{-1}((b-\epsilon,b])$ is uncountable and $f^{-1}((-\infty,b-\epsilon])$ is countable.
>
> If $f$ satisfies 1, then $f$ is an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable real-valued function on $X.$
>
> Suppose that $f$ satisfies 2.
> Then, $f^{-1}((c,\infty))$ is countable if $b<c$ since there exists a positive real number $\epsilon$ such that $b+\epsilon<c.$
> Then, $X\setminus f^{-1}((c,\infty))=f^{-1}((-\infty,c])$ is countable if $c\leq b.$
> So, $f$ is an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable real-valued function on $X.$
>
> Suppose that $f$ satisfies 3.
> Then, $f^{-1}((c,\infty))$ is countable if $b\leq c.$
> Then, $X\setminus f^{-1}((c,\infty))=f^{-1}((-\infty,c])$ is countable if $c<b$ since there exists a positive real number $\epsilon$ such that $c<b-\epsilon.$
> So, $f$ is an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable real-valued function on $X.$

Is my solution ok?
Even if my solution is ok, the conditions 1, 2 and 3 are not simple.
How to improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The case $A = \Bbb R$. Then for all $a \in \Bbb R$, $f^{-1}((a,\infty))$ is countable. Since
   $$ X = f^{-1}(\Bbb R) = f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_n (-n,\infty)\right)=\bigcup_n f^{-1}\left((-n,\infty)\right)$$
   we have that $X$ is countable.
2. The case $A=(b,\infty)$ for some $b\in\mathbb{R}$. In this case, $f^{-1}((b,\infty))$ is uncountable since $b\notin A.$
   On the other hand, let $\epsilon$ be any positive real number. Then, $f^{-1}((b+\epsilon,\infty))$ is countable since $b+\epsilon\in A$.
   In particular, for any $n \in \Bbb N$, $n>0$, $f^{-1}((b+\tfrac{1}{n},\infty))$ is countable. Since,
   $$f^{-1}((b,\infty))= f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_n (b+\tfrac{1}{n},\infty)\right)=\bigcup_n f^{-1}\left((b+\tfrac{1}{n},\infty)\right)$$
   we have that $f^{-1}((b,\infty))$ is countable. Contradiction. So it is not possible to have $A=(b,\infty)$.
3. The case $A=[b,\infty)$ for some $b\in\mathbb{R}$. In this case, $f^{-1}((b,\infty))$ is countable since $b\in A$.
   Let $\epsilon$ be any positive real number. Then $f^{-1}((b-\epsilon,\infty))$ is uncountable since $b-\epsilon\notin A$. In particular $f^{-1}(\Bbb R)$ is uncountable.
   Note that $f^{-1}((-\infty,b-\epsilon])=X\setminus f^{-1}((b-\epsilon,\infty))$ is countable. In particular, for any $n \in \Bbb N$, $n>0$, $f^{-1}((-\infty,b-\tfrac{1}{n}])$ is countable. Since,
   $$f^{-1}((-\infty,b))= f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_n (-\infty, b-\tfrac{1}{n} )\right)=\bigcup_n f^{-1}\left((-\infty, b-\tfrac{1}{n})\right)$$
   we have that $f^{-1}((-\infty, b))$ is countable. Since $f^{-1}((b,\infty))$ is also countable, we have that $f^{-1}(\Bbb R \setminus \{b\})$ is countable
   and, since $f^{-1}(\Bbb R)$ is uncountable, we have that $f^{-1}(\{b\})$ is uncountable.

**Conclusion**: We have only two cases.

1. $X$ is countable, and then all functions $f:X \to \Bbb R$ are $\mathcal{S}$-measurable.
2. $X$ is uncountable. In this case, $f^{-1}(\Bbb R)$ is uncountable and  if $f$ is $\mathcal{S}$-measurable, then there is $b \in \Bbb R$ such that $f^{-1}(\Bbb R \setminus \{b\})$ is countable and $f^{-1}(\{b\})$ is uncountable. Note that the implication in the other direction is immediate. So, in the case of $X$ being  uncountable, $f$ is $\mathcal{S}$-measurable if and only if there is $b \in \Bbb R$ such that $f^{-1}(\Bbb R \setminus \{b\})$ is countable and $f^{-1}(\{b\})$ is uncountable.

**Remark**: As pointed out by Prof. Axler, the conditions for $\mathcal{S}$-measurability in the two cases above ($X$ countable and $X$ uncountable) can be combined in a single elegant statement:

> $f: X \to \Bbb R$ is $\mathcal{S}$-measurable if and only if there is $E\subseteq X$ such that $X \setminus E$ is countable and $f$ is constant on $E$.

Comment: Perhaps a cleaner way to phrase the condition is that a function $f : X \to \mathbf{R}$ is $\mathcal{S}$-measurable if and only if there is a set $E \subset X$ such that $X \setminus E$ is countable and $f$ is constant on $E$.

Comment: @SheldonAxler , Yes, it is an elegant way to phrase in a single statement the conditions for both cases ($X$ countable and $X$ uncountable) together. Thanks.